# Use global type or fallback to local type

Tags: typescript

I want to have a type that is `globalThis.SomeClass` if `globalThis.SomeClass` exists, but `MyClass` when `globalThis.SomeClass` doesn't exist.

For example, it should be `SomeClass` in this example:

```
declare global {
  class SomeClass {}
}

class MyClass {}
type ResolvedClass = /** ... */; // should equal `SomeClass`
```

And `MyClass` in this example because `SomeClass` doesn't exist in the global scope:

```
class MyClass {}
type ResolvedClass = /** ... */; // should equal `MyClass`
```

This would allow me to have an API that say exports a value like so:

```
export const value: ResolvedClass = new ((globalThis as any).SomeClass ?? MyClass)();
```

...then when someone uses that value it would equal the typings for `globalThis.SomeClass`, but have a fallback if their runtime environment doesn't have those typings. What's the best way to do this?

Here's an example of what I've tried: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8kUAzsfAOKoYQDC0pOAvrs7gLYrACuECAyijYgAspx4I8BEAA8ADihgAXQvTKV0mOiTLZmrIgwAyKMJtVNcuGfKXxFAT1kJh9gCqOQARngBeeACUQYhQIADcQdycAHgcnFAAzJCpMVwALAEtiAD4AbngAenz4Y1NaVQAaeDQuZQB3VPsAfis5BWVY5zcPACZfAKCQ8MiQGI8E+AEhUW5eXIKiyZExXgA6dWotUktrNrsPfuCwiI8o1yy+13gZRRAAO2AdeAAidbNtJ4AuHHhZGBRFf4eL7pW7xEAweCuQKHcLAeCMeH4eCNSHQwYgYBIr4lN6kHJAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work when the global augmentation is done in the same file.

Here's a real life example that seems to work with the `Response` type:

```
import * as undici from "undici";

type Response = (typeof globalThis) extends { "Response": { prototype: infer T } }
  ? T
  : undici.Response;
const Response: (typeof globalThis) extends { "Response": infer T }
  ? T
  : typeof undici.Response = (globalThis as any)["Response"] ?? undici.Response;
```